# Modular JSF with Glassfish

Tags: jsf, plugins, glassfish, modular

I have a huge problem.

I'm trying to create a modular JSF app, like the plugin system in liferay, but less complex.

My question is:

Can I load/unload dynamically a JAR file (module or plugin that will be used for my app) using JSF 2 and Glassfish?

Any suggestion? I need use JSF (without osgi or spring).

Thanks in advance...

Comment: When you are not using a WAR, you can use "touch /WEB-INF/web.xml" to reload your context if it is configured like that. But I don't know JAVA functions that could do that (never searched for them).

Comment: I need a way with no redeploy... Actually I'm loading each jar with a different classloader, this let me unload individually... Modifying ResourceResolver and ExternalContext I can load facelets pages and resources, my problem now is how to register ManagedBean, JSF is not resolving classes from a classloader created in runtime.